# Android Xamarin - App Closes when using image gallery picker

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have an activity that opens the image picker. When starting the gallery the selection intent opens and you are able to choose a photo, this works sometime and on some devices but other times does not work and closes the `Activity` instead of calling `OnActivityResult` (The application appears to be backgrounded, but upon reopening the application restarts)

When it does succeed everything works as expected.

I have tried this:

```
Button menu_upload = menu.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.menu_upload);
menu_upload.Click += (o, e) =>
{
    var imageIntent = new Intent();
    imageIntent.SetType("image/*");
    imageIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraAllowMultiple, true);
    imageIntent.SetAction(Intent.ActionPick);
    StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(imageIntent, "Select Image"), REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE_MULTI);

    // ALSO TRIED THIS WITH SAME RESULT

    /*var imageIntent = new Intent();
    imageIntent.SetType("image/*");
    imageIntent.SetAction(Intent.ActionGetContent);
    StartActivityForResult(
        Intent.CreateChooser(imageIntent, "Select photo"), REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE_MULTI);*/

};
```

It seems looks like the activity is being destroyed when it's backgrounded. How do I do this correctly? Or How do I get the chooser to resume to my activity after the image has been chosen?

I have checked out the other articles on this topic but I am unable to get anything to work.

Comment: I think it's the low memory issue when your app is destroyed in this scenario, this is normal for android apps. I think we can only try to override `onSaveInstanceState()` to store your data and read them back in `onCreate()`

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT But the camera does not reopen the app. Does the user need reopen the application manually?

Comment: yes, the app need to be opened manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The activity that was attempting to launch the picker was launched with an android:noHistory flag set. This means that when the picker is launched and the parent activity is no longer on the screen it is closed by Andriod.

More info can be found in the official documentation here:

[Official Android Activity Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)